# How to stop entire component rerender on every hover event?

Tags: angular

I have a very simple component that displays product info - its main attributes and additional features. Nothing serious - some elements get classes dynamically, a json pipe helps me to display product data and ngFor cycle displays additional features. Here it is:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ProductComponent {
  @Input() product = {
    name: 'test product',
    type: 'dog',
    sex: 'female',
    has_beard: 'very true',
    additional_features: [
      {
        name: 'feature 1',
        description: 'simple feature',
      },
      {
        name: 'feature 2',
        description: 'not that simple feature',
      },
    ],
  };

  getItemClass(x) {
    console.log('getItemClass');
    return 'test-item-class';
  }
  getWrapperClass(X) {
    console.log('getWrapperClass');
    return 'test-wrapper-class';
  }
  onItemHover() {}
  getAdditionalFeatures(product) {
    console.log('getAdditionalFeatures');
    return product.additional_features;
  }
}
```

```
<div [class]="getWrapperClass(product)">
  <div (mouseover)="onItemHover()" [class]="getItemClass(produc)">
    <pre>
      <code>
          {{ product | json }}
      </code>
    </pre>
    <div *ngIf="getAdditionalFeatures(product); let additional_features;">
      <pre *ngFor="let feature of additional_features;">
        <code>
            {{ feature | json }}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I thought it would be nice to add some hover animation! I added an empty mouseover listener and... I didnt get to writing of its contents as I saw that my whole component gets rerendered every mouse move. I added console.log to every getter, and all of them get executed many-many times when I hover my simple component. The component doesnt get rerendered on every mouse move if I remove empty mouseover listener.

Here is the interactive example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1zqaj

Question #1 (theoretical): why would angular ever want to rerender an entire component on every hover event if onhover listener is empty?

Question #2 (practical): how can I prevent angular from rerendering an entire component on every hover event?

Comment: The thing here is that Angular tracks DOM changes a lot - on several lifecycle hooks - and putting calls to methods into DOM elements that are *not* regular event-triggers (like buttons for example) means that on each DOM check the Angular will trigger them. So your hover method (that responds to calculated mouse position) is actually triggering all the other methods you called from the template. Try changing the logic: calculate what you have to in the ts and asing the value to a var, then bind the var in the template, not the method that returns the val.

Comment: @MishaMashina, ok, this actually helped - I wrapped all the values in variables and there are no more rerendering. But what if I want my classes to be dynamic? Classes depend on product properties and I plan on changing these properties with some logic that is not related to onhover listener

Comment: It all depends on how you get your data. If you get product properties from subscription, for example, call those value-setting methods inside the subscription block. Granted, there might be situations in which calling a method from template is inescapable, but I think in this case you can actuallly evade it.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment on your question says, this is normal behavior.

To avoid that, you can either detach your component from the change detector (advanced), or you can use an rxjs approach

```html
<div #target>
  Your html code here 
</div>
```

```
@ViewChild('target', { static: true }) targetRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

ngOnInit() {
  fromEvent(this.targetRef.nativeElement, 'mouseover')
    .subscribe();
}
```

Now that you have control over the event, you can use operators such as `debounceTime`, `throttleTime`, `distinctUntilChanged`, etc

With that approach, you need to be careful about memory leaks, so be sure to unsubscribe from your event when the component gets destroyed !